# Openpyxl sheet property `filterMode` doesn't seem to work correctly

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

When I use the sheet property `filterMode`, setting it to `True` for a sheet, the filter doesn't appear in the first row, i.e. I would expect there to be small buttons to the right in each column of the first row, opening lists with the values used in that column.

I do notice a text `Filter Mode` in the left bottom corner of the Excel Window.

Here is the code that I tested with:

```
import openpyxl as xl

s_xl_file = 'c:/temp/test-openpyxl.xlsx'

tu_data = (
    ('Col A', 'Col B'),
    (25, 30),
    (100, 250)
)

wb          =   xl.Workbook()
ws          =   wb.active
ws.title    =   'Test'

for tu_row in tu_data:
    ws.append(tu_row)

ws_props            =   ws.sheet_properties
ws_props.filterMode =   True

wb.save(s_xl_file)
```

Am I doing something wrong here, or does filter mode refer to something else than the filter function in the `Data` ribbon of Excel?

Version data:

- OS: Windows 10 64 bit
- Python: 3.8.5, 64 bit
- Openpyxl: 3.0.3
- Excel: 365 MSO (16.0.113001.20266) 32 bit, used to open the Excel workbook afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I doing something wrong here, or does filter mode refer to something else than the filter function in the Data ribbon of Excel?

I made the same mistake. `filterMode` refers to something else. Specifically, it's a [flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.sheetproperties?view=openxml-2.8.1) indicating whether the worksheet has one or more autofilters or advanced filters on. Setting it to True doesn't give you the filtering functionality.

To enable the little filtering buttons for the entire sheets, add this:

```py
ws.auto_filter.ref = ws.dimensions
ws.auto_filter.add_filter_column(0, [])
```

You can get rid of this, as it achieves nothing:

```py
ws_props            =   ws.sheet_properties
ws_props.filterMode =   True
```

See the documentation: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filters.html